# Identify bullet points in MS Excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am reading columns in MS Excel using Apache POI but the code is not able to identify bullet point. I am trying this:

```
String cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
if(cellValue.contains("•")){}
```

but this is not working. the `cellvalue` is giving some garbage value in case of bullet point and this is why it is not able to compare in my if condition.

Can anyone please suggest solution ?

Comment: try using cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString() and then check for  `\u2022` which is unicode for "•" ?

Comment: This works perfectly fine . Thank you so much Garry !!

Comment: Glad it worked for you, please accept the answer so that it will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString()` and then check for `\u2022` which is unicode for "•"